# Weather Indicator App stopped working

Tags: 12.04

I've been using the weather indicator for a while now on 12.04 and for the past day or so it hasn't been able to update. It just shows the same weather icon (the sun) and the same temperature all day. Right now it's 2AM and it thinks it's sunny outside at 72 degrees when it's actually about 62 degrees outside right now. From the drop down menu it just keeps saying 'refreshing, please wait'
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it through the software center, logging off/restarting and nothing seems to work. Any thoughts for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about Internet connectivity?

Comment: My Internet connectivity is excellent and I can confirm that Indicator-weather does not update (11.10 and 12.04)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This is bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+bug/964365 It's fixed in quantal and the PPA. A fix is pending for 12.04.

Comment: Confirmed, it now works again in 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is in unreachable www.earthtools.org - or rather unexpected answer from there. I usually get very slow (10+ seconds) 404 from there.

In indicator logs (~/.cache/indicator-weather.log) you can see a lot of entries like:
ERROR - Weather: error reaching url 'http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/[your position]

Comment: This is correct. See this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+bug/1030322

Comment: see alternative "my-weather-indicator" here: http://ubuntuguide.net/weather-indicator-in-ubuntu-12-04-unity#comment-13079

Answer (score 3):

Remove indicator-weather and install better and more functional and updated my-weatherindicator with geolocation support.

ppa at https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/indicators

Comment: I think that's good advice.  I used to prefer the indicator-weather but lately my-weather-indicator has definitely moved ahead, especially since indicator-weather never seems to have fixed the clock to use daylight-savings-time.  And Atareao seems to have been putting lots of effort into improving my-weather-indicator; it's become very reliable and stable.  (I run it on 12.04 and on 12.10.)