# weather indicator stuck on "refreshing"

Tags: indicator, weather

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weather Indicator App stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169215/weather-indicator-app-stopped-working)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Weather Indicator, but it's stuck on "Refreshing, please wait" for the current temperature. Everything else seems to work. There have been updates several times over the past week or so, and it was just a few days ago that I noticed the problem. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with no extra themes.

Comment: Hmmm... it started working 15 min. ago, and I haven't been on my computer during that time. I guess posting questions here magically fixes things! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could try switching to my-weather-indicator from ppa:atareao/atareao to cover the same functionality. I'd found them both to be flaky, but a few updates later, my-weather-indicator seems to be much better.

Comment: thanks, this also works for 11.10, indicator-weather buggy as of https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+bug/964365