# Weather Indicator - Can't apply location setting

Tags: 12.10, indicator, weather

After choosing location I cannot apply all the settings. When pressing apply, nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea why that is?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug and you should report it on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/weather-indicator/+bug/1030322), as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169215/weather-indicator-app-stopped-working). I can confirm I can reproduce this. Instead, you can try **my-weather-indicator**. Type in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/indicators
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error trying to set the location for indicator-weather. So I installed my-weather-indicator. I can set the location but I get no data. Don't know what to do...

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/indicators` gave me an error, but on another site I found `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao` that worked.